# Registering POJO Support or JSON Providers for JAX-RS programmatically

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am developing plugins for an application. The plugins are basically JAX-RS endpoints. They are packaged and deployed to the classpath of the application which runs a Jetty and registers them. Example:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Product get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return Product.lookup(id);
}
```

To be able to return arbitrary POJOs via JAX-RS and I wanted to enable POJOMapping or explicitly register something like a Jackson Provider.

I know I could do this if I had access to the `web.xml` or via `Client` configuration [[Jersey JSON Documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html)].

Unfortunately I do not have access to these methods given the plugin architecture.

Is there any way to register a provider such as Jackson in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JAX-RS `Application` class as part of your application to register a JSON-binding provider.  Below is an example of registering [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JSON provider.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class CustomerApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(CustomerService.class);
        return set;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html